# Does it make any differences in meaning when the subordinate clause is at the end or beginning of the sentence?

Tags: meaning, clauses, subordinate-clauses

Does it make any differences in meaning when the subordinate clause is at the end or beginning of the sentence?

**Example 1**

> Mom always makes sure Tom has food to eat before he leaves for school.

**Example 2**

> Before Tom leaves for school, Mom always makes sure he has food to eat.

Comment: No, just a slight difference in emphasis.

Comment: They could mean different things. When does Tom eat? Breakfast or lunch? But native speakers won't always be aware of ambiguities, so you cannot rely on the placement of the clause to determine the meaning. Context is king. We don't know if the temporal clause applies to **eat** or **makes sure**.  You'd have to focus on the locution "have food to eat" in the context of moms providing for their kids about to leave for school in the morning.  Most people, I think, would assume that mom is making lunch, not breakfast, for Tom.

Comment: No: 1. entails 2. and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have stated, these sentences have the same meaning. There might be slight variations in emphasis or implication, but not in denotational meaning. In this case the first sentence places slightly more emphasis on Mom's role, and might be preferred if Mom's activities are the focus of the passage; the second places slightly more emphasis on Tom's action, and might be preferred if you were discussing Tom's morning routine, but again, the two forms have the same meaning.

Answer (score -1):

While the two have nearly identical meaning, there is a notable inferential difference.

The first sentence reflects more on mom's tendencies, and does so in a much broader and looser sense of time. It implies that mom *always* looks out for Tom, and has for years; it would make sense to follow that up with more about how mom looks after Tom, but *today* is not that important.

The second sentence would be used not only when the focus is more on Tom, but more on a particular day, a day, for example when a specific event occurs in the afternoon, for example.

"Mom always makes sure Tom has food to eat before he leaves for school; in fact, it gives her a sense of contentment as a mother."

"Before Tom leaves for school, Mom always makes sure he has food to eat, but on that first Tuesday in May, Tom went to class hungry...."

Answer (score -1):

Think about it with a different clause:

“I set the alarm to go off at noon.”

“At noon, I set the alarm to go off.”

In this setting, the meanings are almost entirely different.  In the first, at some unknown time, I set an alarm for 12:00; the second, when I set the alarm, it was noon, but what time the alarm will sound is unspecified.

Your sentences have an analogous difference.  In the first, at some point in the preceding day or that morning, Mom does something to make sure that Tim has food to eat in the morning; in the second, during that morning, Mom makes sure that Tim can eat at some point.  The word “has” is ambiguous.  Is the food merely in his possession or is he actually swallowing it?

Semantically, we know what is happening: first thing in the morning, Mom prepares some food and gives it to Tim to carry to school.  Since the meaning is so clear, we gloss over minor differences in how they are expressed.